# compojure POST request parameters are empty when app deployed to heroku

Tags: heroku, clojure, compojure

My code is very simple:

```
(def form-test
  "<html><body><form action=\"/\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"ss\"/><input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"/></form></body></html>")

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] form-test)
  (POST "/" req (str "the req: " req))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))
```

whenever I try my app on my local machine it works fine, I can see the request parameters, but when I deploy the same thing to heroku the request parameters are always empty... what's going on?

Comment: There's not much information to figure out the root of the problem. Is there a public repository where people can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: How about linking to your Heroku app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I resolved my issue, the problem was the way my program was being executed in Heroku.
My Procfile previously:

```
web: lein run -m myapp.core
```

all I did is change it to:

```
web: java $JVM_OPTS -jar myapp.jar
```

basically I had to execute my program as a compiled jar.